# Pay using UPI option not showing merchant name in UPI apps?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, payumoney, google-pay

I have integrated PayU Money SDK in my Android app. Everything works fine except when the user selects pay via UPI.
For example, while using pay via Google Pay the merchant name is not shown. Instead it shows as PayU Money has requested money from you on your Google app. I want to show merchant name there instead of PayU Money has requested. I want show merchant name in the yellow colored area, is it possible?

[image: The merchant name should appear after "Dear Customer,".]

[image: The merchant name should also appear above the Pay and Decline buttons.]